# Trying to stack with Z-Index

Tags: css

I'm just starting a new project and I'm having trouble with using the `z-index` function in CSS. It just isn't working no matter what I try. I've tried swapping the values of both div's `z-index` and it still wont work.

```
#outerbox {
    position:absolute;
    height:700px;
    width:700px;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    left:570px;
    top:125px;
    z-index:1;
}

#innerbox {
    position:relative;
    height:680px;
    width:680px;
    background-color:grey;
    display:grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:10px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: remove z-index from outer element and adjust only the one of inner

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: share full code with the html also so we can see that it's not working